# How to make a method that is used only for testing?

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

Hi guys I'm trying to test the declarative exception handling in the parent controller. The problem is this

> Exception handler methods must be present at compile time. Specifically, exception handler methods which metaprogrammed onto a controller class are not supported.

Source: http://geekswithblogs.net/zakariacse/archive/2014/07/06/grails-basic-controllerspart-4.aspx

Adding a method just for the testing is one of my solution but I think that it is not a good practice to make it exposed in the development or production environment. Is there any ways to make it available only in test environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to add a method that's only available in the test environment in order to test the exception handling? Personally, I'd try to test this by calling the controller with an invalid set of parameters (that causes an exception to be thrown), or use mocking/metaprogramming to change an action such that it always throws an exception

Here is one way to make a method only available in the test environment, though it's not something I'd be inclined to use myself:

```
class Foo {

  def testOnlyMethod() {
    if (environment.current = Environment.TEST) {
      // do whatever this method is supposed to do in the test env
    } else {
      // in non-test envs, this method behaves similarly to a non-existent method
      throw new MissingMethodException()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there other way like using annotation?

@CompileAt('Test')
def testMethod(){}

Comment: @FARExistence generally you should put all test code in `src/test` so there shouldn't be any need for something like `@CompileAt('Test')`